# Вывод количества записей за неделю, месяц

Tags: wordpress

не могу найти как вывести лишь количество записей, за промежуток времени, неделю или месяц.
нахожу постоянно вывод самих записей

Answer (score 0):

```
  $week = date('W');
  $year = date('Y');
  $query = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $year . '&w=' . $week );
  echo 'Количество постов за неделю:' . count ($query);
```

Comment: оформил вот так все это дело https://pastebin.com/JCu1edNq однако в итоге вывелся текст одной записи. а не число. мне нужно так чтобы , произвольный текст "за неделю опубликовано" и число "10 записей"

Comment: Пардон, не заметил, что Вам нужно количество постов, а не сами посты.

Исправил. Теоретически должно работать.

Comment: а на сайте, не может обработать запрос.......